# Fuzzy searching a large set of data efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, fuzzy-search

I have a database in the following format:

```
"filename": {
        "url": "base64 of Zlib compressed URL to decrease size of file",
        "date": "Date added to database",
        "size": "Size of file in URL(not always present)"
}
```

The format is tree-like. for example:

```
"dirname": {
        "url": "base64 of Zlib compressed URL to decrease size of file",
        "date": "Date added to database",
        [...files and directories in this directory...]
}
```

can contain more files and directories.

---

### Goal

I'm trying to **fuzzy search just the names** and **return the URL/date(/size)** of entries in the database. It currently has 6.5M strings with an average length of about 36 characters. Duplicate names are present in the database.

---

### What I've tried

I figured it would be faster to load the data to RAM first. I have only 8GB on my laptop so i figured to lower the usage i would save the data in list format, where the URL is compressed with `Zlib` to further decrease RAM usage. The format is something like this:

```py
[["file or directory name", "zlib compressed url", "date", "size if exists"], ...]
```

which rounds up to around 3GBs currently.
Then i splice the list into 20 pieces using an iterator, and passing the iterator to a function and running that in a separate Process.

```py
results = manager.list() # python multiprocessing shared list
#in a loop that splices into n pieces(20 currently):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.slice_search, args=(results, name, iter(self.minimal_data[start:i]), function_to_use, min_score,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
```

the "function_to_use" is currently fuzz.QRatio from fuzzywuzzy, "slice_search" is a function that appends the data into a shared list if the result of "function_to_use" on the string is more than a certain threshold.
The results are in stored in a similar format:

```py
[["score", "file or directory name", "zlib compressed url", "date", "size if exists"], ...]
```

and are sorted after the search is over and saved to a file in human-readable format(the URL's are also decompressed).

---

### Problem

with all of this it still takes about 20-30 seconds to do the search. I truly believe there's a better way, but i don't have the knowledge required to make it happen. My final goal is to get it to work at least faster than 10 seconds. I would appreciate any help or direction you can point me to.

Comment: The bad performance is coming from the large data size: using multiprocessing will involve slow inter-process communications. If the computing work per string is small, this is probably better to directly load parts of the file from the disk in each process. However, since the input file looks like a json file, I think you cannot do that. What is the size of the input file? What is the speed of your hard drive? Did you try to use the (generally faster) PyPy JIT-based interpreter?

Comment: If the data format is a problem i could change it, however i figured it would be much faster to process the data after loading it to RAM. The file is about 1.6GB's formatted in a way that is human readable and can be converted to usable data without ever parsing the json. I have an SSD but don't think that affects much since the loading to RAM part isn't very important to me performance-wise. I did try to run with PyPy but for some reason it's about 3X slower. It might be because fuzzywuzzy is already very optimized as is, and not much can be improved there(I'm curious about other libs tho).

Comment: let me clarify the performance-heavy part of the code is waiting for the fuzzy search results for each string within the processes, not much else is done in each process.

Comment: Ok, so if I am correct data can be loaded once and do not change over time. Moreover, you make multiple `fuzzywuzzy` calls with different string parameters. Right? If this is correct, you can split data only once and keep split parts within processes waiting for multiple computations. This should avoid the very slow implicit communications between processes. That being said, Python may not be the most suited tool here.

Comment: Understood. I'm currently looking to create an alternative with C++, and i'll try to look for faster alternatives there as well. I'll update the post after in case anyone's interested

Comment: I am still not quite sure about your goal. So have one user defined input string that you and you would like to compare to the 6.5m strings. As a result do you only need the best match, the best n matches, all matches with a score above a certain threshold, or really all result?

Comment: @maxbachmann only those scoring above a certain threshold, in no specific order. They are later on sorted and saved to a file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this answer I will work on the following data:

```py
import string
import random
random.seed(18)
str_options = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + ' '
query = \'\'.join(random.choice(str_options) for _ in range(30))
choices = [\'\'.join(random.choice(str_options) for _ in range(30)) for s in range(6500000)]
```

I will not use any multiprocessing for now, but this can be done in a parallel way aswell.

1. this is about what your current solution looks like:

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
results = []
for choice in choices:
    if fuzz.QRatio(query, choice) >= 80:
        results.append(choice)
```

As you mentioned fuzzywuzzy already uses python-Levenshtein for the levenshtein calculations which is pretty optimised. However before calculating fuzzywuzzy checks whether both strings are empty or equal so it can return early without calculating the levenshtein distance. While this sounds like a good idea it really is not, since checking whether two strings are the same requires to iterate over the whole string to check it. It is a lot better to remove the common prefix and suffix before the levenshtein calculation (speeds it up so e.g. for equal strings it is linear in time). This is a bit slower when the strings are exactly the same, but when working on fuzzy data this is very unlikely the case.
This first solution runs in about `55 seconds` on my machine

2. This replaces fuzzywuzzy with [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz) (I am the author) which is a MIT Licensed reimplementation of FuzzyWuzzy that is mostly implemented in C++ and performs a lot better since it fixes quite a few performance issues in FuzzyWuzzy

```py
from rapidfuzz import fuzz
results = []
for choice in choices:
    if fuzz.QRatio(query, choice) >= 80:
        results.append(choice)
```

This only requires about `18 seconds` on my machine, so it is already about a 3x improvement. Another issue is that using fuzz.QRatio preprocesses both strings to lowercase them and remove some unwanted characters. While this generally makes sence this means that the query here gets preprocess 6.5 million times instead of once.

3. This only preprocesses the query once

```py
from rapidfuzz import fuzz, utils
results = []
processed_query = utils.default_process(query)
for choice in choices:
    processed_choice = utils.default_process(choice)
    if fuzz.ratio(processed_query, processed_choice, score_cutoff=80):
        results.append(choice)
```

It takes `14 seconds` on my machine. This shows that you might want to store your filenames in a preprocessed way aswell, so you do not have to preprocess them when searching either (this would get it down to around `11 seconds`). At this point the main time requirement is calculating the levenshtein distance which is a O(m*n) operation. So it would be good to reduce the amount of results where this has to be done. A quick way that is already used by RapidFuzz by default is comparing the length of the two strings, since they can not reach the required ratio when they have a big length difference and can be calculated in constant time, since the lengths are already known anyways. However in my test case here this will never apply since all strings have a length of 30. When a even faster solution is required you can still calculate this on multiple cores. You can use the C++ version [RapidFuzz-cpp](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz-cpp) aswell (it does not has all features from the python version yet, but enough to implement this aswell)

The pure C++ version of RapidFuzz still needs a little work and especially documentation, but it can be implemented in the following way:

```cpp
using rapidfuzz::string_utils::default_process;
using rapidfuzz::fuzz::CachedRatio;

std::string query("example");
std::vector<std::string> choices{"example", "example2", "example3"};

std::string processed_query = default_process(query);
std::vector<std::string> results;
CachedRatio<std::string> scorer(processed_query);
for (const auto& choice : choices) {
    std::string processed_choice = default_process(choice);

    if (scorer.ratio(processed_choice, 80)) {
        results.push_back(choice);
    }
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! This is amazing! I processed the names in the database and applied what you said and the results are unbelievable! for score values above 70 it's done in less than a second! and the only thing holding it back for lower scores is the result of 20 processes writing to a single shared list, but even then it's at least 90% faster for scores as low as 40. i guess it might not be necessary to re-write the whole thing in C++ after all. Thanks!

Comment: I might still move to C++ though as the little bit of it that i re-wrote there shows a noticeably less RAM usage(using a vector<list<string>>) as well as a 50% faster loading to RAM using the same approach as the python version.

Comment: Done. It takes 400ms for a string of length 6 using 20 async threads, and uses a lot less RAM. amazing :)